# Failed to publish artifacts with Nexus beind https

Tags: ant, nexus, ivy

Having problem publishing artifact using Ivy with an Ant script. I have the Nexus sits behind a HTTPS reverse proxy. The credentials provided in ivysettings has system admin which I managed to retrieve artifacts out of it.

Ant script returns this error when ivy:publish was called

`impossible to publish artifacts for [org]#[module];working@[client-machine]: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1567)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:225)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:148)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.put(RepositoryResolver.java:234)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.publish(ChainResolver.java:244)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:281)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:260)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:172)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.publish(Ivy.java:600)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish.doExecute(IvyPublish.java:311)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)`

This is the only log being captured with the publish.

`2017-11-06 13:27:21 WARN  [AuthtokenFetcherImpl-task] MY_USERNAME com.sonatype.central.secure.nexus.plugin.internal.AuthtokenFetcherImpl - Failed to fetch authtoken: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to secure.central.sonatype.com:443 [secure.central.sonatype.com/207.223.241.90] failed: connect timed out`